# How to re-initialize a class object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making the typical text game program and I'm stuck on the restart function. I want to restart the room instances, but when I try to delete the object I get AttributeError: room1. Here's some pseudo-ish code:

```
class Room:
inventory = []

    __init__(self, itemsInRoom, doors):
    #makes a room instance and puts some items and doors into the room
        self.roomItems = []
        self.roomDoor = []
        for item in itemsInRoom:
        #puts initial items into the room
            self.roomItems.append(item)
        for eachDoor in doors:
        #tells the instance what doors there are
            self.roomDoor.append[doors]

    Def functionsBlahBlah():
        Pass

class RoomNumber:
    room1 = Room(['stool', 'tavern wench', 'bar keep'], ['north', 'east'])
    room2 = Room(so on and so forth)

    def functionsBlahBlah():
        Pass

def restartFunction():
    del RoomNumber.room1
    del RoomNumber.room2
    startGame()

def startGame():
    RoomNum()#initializes rooms
    main()

startGame()
```

So anyway, I try to delete RoomNumber.room1 in the restart function so I can turn around and initialize it again with it's original items and stuff. As I said though, I get an error. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This code has lots of errors, but none seem related to "re-initializing class object".  Once you fix the 9 syntax errors, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me as well. Could you just reinitialise the parent object and let python's garbage collection deal with deleting? I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @J.Cocoe whatever, it's pseudo code meant to give the general idea of what I'm trying to do. If you don't understand the question then there's no need to make useless comments. Obviously it doesn't work fine or I wouldn't be asking a question on it.

Comment: Josh: When I fixed the obvious syntax errors and ran it, it did not give me an "AttributeError: room1", so one of the things you think is inconsequential actually isn't.  That's where you're going wrong.  The "general idea" is fine.

Comment: I just went ahead and got rid of the restart function. I'm thinking maybe I have to do def __init__(self): in the RoomNum class as well though and set room1 etc in there. Idk. I'm still noob.